# Array being populated with JSX Elements not rendering/updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

This may be a quick fix but I have been racking my brain for the past little while, and could really use another set of eyes to take a look.

Basically I am trying to render an array full of generated JSX elements. I fell like I have done this a million times, but it does not seem to work here.

Heres the code:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import css from './Search.scss';

import Header from '../SectionHeader/Header';
import SearchItem from '../SearchItem/SearchItem';

const Search = (props) => {

  const { coinObject, coinKeys } = props;

  let searchResults = [];                              // Array in question

  const findResults = (searchText) => {
    searchResults = [];                                // Reset the array to blank for each new character typed in input
    for(let i = 0; i < coinKeys.length; i++) {         
      const { FullName } = coinObject[coinKeys[i]];    // App specific logic, not important, or the problem here
      if(FullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) && (searchResults.length < 5)) {    
        console.log(FullName, searchText);             // Prints the correct Full name based off of the searched text
        searchResults.push(<SearchItem key={i} searchText={FullName} />);
      }
    }
    console.log(searchResults);                        // Prints the updated array with all react elements
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header title='Find Coins!' />
      <div className={css.searchContainer}>
        <div className={css.inputContainer}>
          <input onChange={input => findResults(input.target.value)} className={css.searchInput} type='text' placeholder='Start Typing a Coin'/>
        </div>
        { searchResults }
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

And the SearchItem Component, which is super simple:

```
import React from 'react'
import css from './SearchItem.scss';

const SearchItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={css.searchItem}>
      {props.searchText}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchItem;
```

For a little bit of context, this component just gets a giant object of data, and will display the first 5 instances of what matches the input text. I am trying to make one of those search filter things, where as you type it suggests things that match from the data.

The array gets updated, and I can see the JSX objects in the array, they just do not render. I have a feeling it is due to the array not re-rendering?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `Search` component into a stateful component and store the `searchResults` in your state instead, so that when it is updated your component will be re-rendered.

**Example**

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  state = { searchResults: [] };

  findResults = searchText => {
    const { coinObject, coinKeys } = this.props;
    const searchResults = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < coinKeys.length; i++) {
      const { FullName } = coinObject[coinKeys[i]];
      if (
        FullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) &&
        searchResults.length < 5
      ) {
        searchResults.push(FullName);
      }
    }

    this.setState({ searchResults });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Header title="Find Coins!" />
        <div className={css.searchContainer}>
          <div className={css.inputContainer}>
            <input
              onChange={event => findResults(event.target.value)}
              className={css.searchInput}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Start Typing a Coin"
            />
          </div>
          {this.state.searchResults.map((fullName, i) => (
            <SearchItem key={i} searchText={fullName} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will go ahead and use this method instead. Also, any reason you just add the text to the array, and then iterate and create the SearchItem component in the render function, rather than putting the JSX element as a whole in the array like before? Thanks!

Comment: @nicetoCyou Great! JSX is just a bunch of [`React.createElement` calls](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwZQpghgTgxgFgSQC5gLYAJ0HoB8Q&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=) , and "the React way" is to derive your React elements from state and props in the render method. Putting elements in state can cause subtle bugs that are hard to debug.